# Putting New Information Into Excel File Python

Tags: python, excel, sorting

I have a script that sorts through cells and will pickout the specific keywords and put them into a new column. The problem I am running into is that when the new information is put in, it deletes everything else in the excel file. I want it to put the new information in and not delete the existing information in the excel file.

Code:

```
    #Import Pandas and Re
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import ExcelWriter
    from pandas import ExcelFile
    import re


    #Opens excel Workbook
    excel_workbook = 'memory.xlsx'

    sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excel_workbook, sheet_name='Memory')
    excel_memory = sheet1['Description']

    #Search descriptions for PC4 & PC3
    MemType = re.findall('PC4|PC3|PC2', str(excel_memory))

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(MemType)
    writer = ExcelWriter('memory2.xlsx')
    df2.to_excel(writer,'Memory',startcol=6, startrow=1, index=False, header=False)
    writer.save()
```

Table:

| Part Number | Manufacturer | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 752370-091 | HP | HP 32GB (1x32GB) 2RX4 PC4-2133 Registered Memory WITH 1 YEAR WARRANTY |
| 716112-081 | HP | HP 32GB (1X32GB) 1Gx4 PC3-10600H MEMORY MODULE WITH 1 YEAR WARRANTY |
| 752370-091 | HP | HP 32GB (1x32GB) 2RX4 PC4-2133 Registered Memory WITH 1 YEAR WARRANTY |
| 752370-091U | HP | HP 32GB (1x32GB) 2RX4 PC4-2133 Memory with 1 year warranty |
| 715166-S21 | HP | HP 32GB (1X32GB) 1Gx4 PC3-10600H MEMORY MODULE WITH 1 YEAR WARRANTY |

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to a file instead of overwriting it, pass `mode='a'` to `ExcelWriter`.

In your code, you would make this change:

```
writer = ExcelWriter('memory2.xlsx', mode='a')
df2.to_excel(writer,'Memory',startcol=6, startrow=1, index=False, header=False)
```

Refer: [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: I tried adding the new mode but it creates a new sheet in the workbook with the data. How do I write it to the existing sheet or how can I bring that other data into the newly written sheet?

Comment: Have you tried passing the `sheet_name` parameter to `to_excel` with the name of the sheet to which you want to append?

Comment: I tried adding it here and it just creates a new sheet.



`df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Memory',startcol=6, startrow=1, index=False, header=False)`